# How to create a Stored Procedure with Optional DateTime Parameters in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

So the parameters in the stored procedure are optional, meaning they can be null. The issue with my cade is that there is no output whenever I call the SP. I need my params to be able to accept null as well

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GET`(
in startDate DATETIME,
in endDate DATETIME
)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM DB.table
WHERE
DB.table.colunm >= startDate
AND
DB.table.colunm  <= endDate;
END
```

when I call the stored procedure, I never get any result

```
call GET(2022-05-28, 2022-05-30)

call GET(null, null)
```

Comment: What does NULL in the parameter value means? "with no restrictions"? if so then use COALESCE() and replace NULL with the value which is maximal or minimal for the datatype.

Comment: @Akina what I mean by null is that I want to have the ability to not pass any date to the SP and have it return all the data. Like ignore the where and just select *

Comment: `.. WHERE DB.table.column BETWEEN COALESCE(startDate, '1000-01-01 00:00:00') AND COALESCE(endDate, 9999-12-31 23:59:59);`. PS. BEGIN-END may be removed, they're excess, and in this case you do not need to use DELIMITER additionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve all records when you pass the `null` value, you can use the `IF... ELSE... Statement` to determine what your `Stored Procedure` will select.

Check the following SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETDT(
in startDate DATETIME,
in endDate DATETIME
)
BEGIN
if startDate is null or endDate is null then
  SELECT * FROM test;
else
  SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE
  test.sdate >= startDate
  AND
  test.edate  <= endDate;
end if;
END
```

See the result from [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rUda2ncfSLbHbgfcpTTgKY/0).

Answer (score 1):

If your query is complex and you don't want to create multiple select statement you can have the "IF" function inside the "WHERE" statement.

This SP expect 4 input, but in can be null.

example of calls:

1. Call TMF646_GetAppointmentsRaw('' , '' , '', '')
2. Call TMF646_GetAppointmentsRaw('id01', '' , '' ,'2024-01-14T19:41:55.000Z')

```html
  

CREATE PROCEDURE `TMF646_GetAppointmentsRaw`(
   IN input_id VARCHAR(45),
   IN input_status VARCHAR(25),
   IN input_creationDate VARCHAR(50),
   IN input_lastUpdate VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      a.id AS id, 
      status,
      DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.000Z') AS creationDate,
      DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.000Z') AS lastUpdate
   FROM tmforum.appointments a
   WHERE 1=1
      AND IF(input_id != '', a.id, '') LIKE input_id
      AND IF(input_status != '', a.status, '') LIKE input_status
      AND IF(input_creationDate != '', a.created_at, '') = 
          IF(input_creationDate != '', (STR_TO_DATE(input_creationDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.000Z')), '')
      AND IF(input_lastUpdate != '', a.updated_at, '') = 
          IF(input_lastUpdate != '', (STR_TO_DATE(input_lastUpdate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.000Z')), '');
END
```

If '' date is received it will check against '' value as well so the condition will be true.

But if there is value, it will check against created_at value in the db.